# How do I specify a required inheritance for a template class argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following structures:

```
class ElementEx
{
public:
    ElementEx() {}
    AddChild(ElementEx* element) 
    {
        // some stuff
    }
};

class A : ElementEx
{
public:
    A() {}
};

class B : ElementEx
{
public:
    B() {}
};


template <class T>
class MyNewClass : public T
{
public:
    MyNewClass()
    {
        ElementEx* newElement = new ElementEx();
        AddChild(newElement);
    }
};
```

When creating a MyNewClass object, T must inherit from A or B, so MyNewClass will descend from ElementEx. But in my example, the compiler doesn't know this, and can't figure out what AddChild is. How do I make sure the T class is a descendant of ElementEx?

I'm imagining doing

```
((ElementEx*)this)->AddChild(newElement);
```

But that seems really inelegant (and prone to error, if the wrong type is fed in as T), and I figure there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Is this a problem at all? If `A` or `B` are "something" that implements `AddChild`, this will compile just fine. If they're something different, it will break (which is just what one wants!). So either way, it's fine the way it is already, no? You can simply create "something" of type `T`, without that cast. Either `T` is a correct type, or the compiler will barf an error.

Comment: I'm getting the error and I'm not even instantiating any of these things yet. Will hunt through the syntax to make sure I haven't gotten an error in there. My example above is a simplified version for the purpose of asking.

Comment: @Damon The compiler will complain because it doesn't know that `AddChild` is dependent on T in the first pass.  `this->AddChild(newElement)` is the typical way to get around the compile error.

Comment: Boom! Thanks Andrew. Drop that in as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is complaining here because it doesn't know that `AddChild` is dependent on `T` during the first pass.  `AddChild` can be made a dependent name by prepending the call with `this->` hence delaying the lookup to the second pass when `T` is known.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're content that the parent class supports `AddChild` accepting an `ElementEx` you can do this easily using the normal compiler error.

After fixing a bunch of errors in your code (A and B inherit privately, all your classes have private constructors, `AddChild` has no return type) I was able to make it work fine by adding `this->` to the call to `AddChild` because `AddChild` is a dependent name and you indicate that to the compiler by either qualifying the type or by adding `this->`. If you don't anticipate the need for virtual calls to that method you could altenately call `ElementEx::AddChild` to force the correct lookup. Corrected code follows.

```
class ElementEx
{
public:
    ElementEx() {}
    void AddChild(ElementEx* element)
    {
        // some stuff
    }
};

class A : public ElementEx
{
public:
    A() {}
};

class B : public ElementEx
{
public:
    B() {}
};


template <class T>
class MyNewClass : public T
{
public:
    MyNewClass()
    {
        ElementEx* newElement = new ElementEx();
        this->AddChild(newElement);
    }
};

struct Bad {};

int main()
{
    MyNewClass<B> b;          // Compiles.
    MyNewClass<Bad> bad;      // error: 'class MyNewClass<Bad>' has no member named 'AddChild'
}
```

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info on ElementEx::AddChild. Sorry for the errors in the code there; I took what I had and simplified it quickly and missed some stuff. :( Edited code to show your fixes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this nicely, but they all have the basis of using 1.) static assert. 2) Static eval functions.

Personaly, I'd use (in the constructor)

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<ElementEx,T>::value,"T must derive from ElementEx")
```

But there is probably a better way. What is the X part of your problem (what are you trying to achieve with this weird inheritance structure?)

Comment: I have two objects with identical constructors, both inherit from ElementEx. I want to say new Object, tell it which type, and get the right one. I don't want to maintain duplicate code across the constructors.

Comment: :( Maybe I'm looking at the problem the wrong way. I'll think on it some more.

Comment: Additionally, I don't seem to have is_base_of. Doesn't look like I'm using C++11 stuff.